". . . , but thinks by Easter he'll have grown into it"?
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 21)

(It's Christmas. William, the chorister, at home)


William's present is a bike, waiting for him in the communal shed next to the allotments. His old one is still there, ridiculously small. He goes for a ride round the park at the end of the street while Evelyn (his mother) starts lunch. He can only just reach the ground, so he's a little nervous, but thinks by Easter he'll have grown into it.

Is 'he'll have grown into it' meant humorously there or is it usual wording? I could imagine this phrasing applies to clothes and such things, but it's meant humorously in the present context. Maybe, to make things clearer, I have to add I know the meaning of the phrase but because I know its meaning regarding clothes etc. I surmise the phrase could have a humorous flavour in this context (bicycle).

Please be careful with the word verbiage, especially the phrase usual verbiage. In any event, it never takes a and is very misused. The usual verbiage could refer to the contents on an NDA, for example.

What do you call an NDA?

See StE English L&U Meta https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15796/why-was-this-question-about-the-stylistic-usage-of-grow-into-it-closed

"Firstly, I don't see any humour, it's a standard idiom for an oversized item (be it shoes, trousers, a coat…) given to a growing child. Fev's answer even includes a definition from Cambridge Dictionary: Never buy a bike that’s too big and expect your child to grow into it." - Author: Mari-Lou A

"There is no dictionary reference indicating it can be used humorously, if the "child" were instead a grown man and the protagonist said to himself "by Easter I'll have grown into it" that would be funny because a person by the time they are in their late teen or mid-twenties will have stopped growing." - Author Mari-Lou A

Grow into

to become large enough for (a certain size of clothing)

Ben will grow into Billy's shoes in a year or two. (M-W)


Also

If children grow into clothes, they gradually become big enough to wear them.
(BEGIN TO FIT) to become tall enough or big enough to wear or use something:

Never buy a bike that’s too big and expect your child to grow into it. (Cambridge)


In this context, the usage is humorous, and means that by Easter he will have grown up enough to comfortably use the new bike. In other words, his legs will then be long enough and touch the ground comfortably.

I don't see that this is even humorous, just a natural extension of the idea of 'growing into' (or 'out of') clothes.

I meant to explain it better. I think the context is humorous, not the usage. Or at least endearing. The situation is presented from the point of view of the child.

I think the meaning of the phrasal verb here is this:

to become more confident in a new job, etc. and learn to do it better

She's still growing into her new role as a mother.
[Oxford Learner's Dictionary]
I don't see any humorous usage of the phrasal verb here. We are told that William is a little nervous but he'll probably have overcome his nervousness by Easter.

I think the mention of his height indicates it could be literal, but I guess it's not conclusive.
